# Normalize the dark and bright areas in an image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, histogram

I have an image of a textile that has some dark and some bright areas mixed together. Is there any approach that I uniformly normalize them? The end goal is to detect the defects out.

I know histogram equalization and stuff but that isn’t solving my problem.
Any suggestion in this regard are highly appreciated.

Update 1:
I can't post the original image as it's confidential but the brightness of picture is like the image below, some areas are darker than the others.
[image: Image 1]

Update 2: So my original image is somewhat like this!
[image]

Comment: Not quite following your description.   Could you please post the image?

Comment: @MarkLavin check my Edit 1 please.

Comment: Run a massive symmetrical LPF to find the center and ellipsoid of the bright blob. Then do a fit to the mean brightness to find the distance to the source of illumination (if you don't know it already), and apply a Lambertian correction to the intensity.

Comment: You could also use a LPF (I'm assuming this stands for Low Pass Filter) with a kernel somewhat larger than the fabric texture and then subtract that from the original image.

Answer (score 0):

I think this method is not safe for colors and also I assume that a better image can be taken later so that less light can damage the fabric.

```py
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np

pth = sys.path[0]
org = cv2.imread(pth+'/tx3.png')

shade = cv2.medianBlur(org, 13)
shade = cv2.cvtColor(shade, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
shade = cv2.cvtColor(shade, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

flat = (org+(1-(shade/255))*~shade*2)/2
norm = flat*255/np.max(flat)

cv2.imwrite(pth+'/shade.jpg', shade)
org = np.hstack((org, flat))
out = np.hstack((shade, norm))
cv2.imwrite(pth+'/Flatten.jpg', np.vstack((org, out)))
```

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: @sh-navid thanks for your answer but with your algorithm, I get the white flatten image.

Comment: Hello :) First try this method on the image you showed us .

Comment: @sh-navid look at the image 2 (update 2) please. That is my original image.

Comment: I think you need a better picture. Because in the second image, the light seems to be so much in some parts that the components of the image are lost. Is there a possibility of better physical imaging?

Comment: That's the problem that the light is not uniform, and there is no way I can change the lighting.